# Why and how to use Url Rendering in Sitecore

Tags: components

I am new to Sitecore. Can any one please tell me why and how to use URL Rendering in Sitecore?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Sitecore community.
Url rendering is explained [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/mvc-and-renderings.html) .

> **Url Rendering**
>
> This rendering type renders the response of a HTTP GET request onto
>   the current page.
>
> You can use it if you need to screen scrape HTML from another system.
>   Can sometimes be used to avoid using iframes.

In Genreal, if  you need to display any website in iframe in your website, you can use Url rendering.

Comment: It should be noted that it is currently supported for legacy reasons, it is not usually a recommended practice if you are starting new projects.